# Y'all come back now, y'hear?

Tags: registre-familier, formulation-idiomatique

Récemment j'ai dit à mon chat : « Tu dois retourner, tu entends ? » pendant que je lui permettais de sortir, mais je pense qu'il y a une meilleure traduction  pour cette phrase en anglais, indiquée dans le titre ?

Comment: Tu dois revenir, tu sais ?

Comment: Ah merci @cl-r je l'ai déjà entendu mais je ne me suis pas souvenu.

Comment: C'est pour un chat qui a quel niveau en français ? Il faut faire attention ces bêtes là sont susceptibles.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Le chat me fait penser de cette phrase ; il ne comprends pas français

Comment: You all is mostly southern American English and is always plural. NEVER singular. I thought that translation was not allowed here...

Comment: Le chat fait penser **à quoi?**

Comment: @Lambie thanks for that--sometimes I nail the de/à and sometimes miss it completely

Comment: For the sake of my discussion with @Lambie, were you looking for a different French translation of "Y'all come back...", or a different English translation of "Tu dois retourner..."?

Comment: I wasn't clear in the question I think (I saw the discussion)--to clarify, it was my speaking to the cat that caused me to think of the phrase and wonder at a better way to translate it. In any case, I have learned several different versions from your response and the comments that have been very enlightening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour garder bien le sens, disons familier, tu pourrais dire:

> "Faut revenir, t'entends ?"

Mais il se peut qu'il y ait plusieurs options.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse. Tu et cl-r préfèrent le verbe revenir plus que retourner ; est-il plus français ou va-t-il mieux ici ?

Comment: Ben c'est juste que ça convient plus à ta phrase - "to come" c'est "venir," n'est-ce pas ? "To come back" serait donc "REvenir" :)

Comment: Et merci encore--quelque fois je ne vois pas ce qui est vraiment évident, surtout si je regarde des détails et pas toute l'idée.

Comment: @BenKnoble *Revenir* vs *retourner* depends on the direction of the action. Revenir is to come back toward the place the action is set in (Je suis revenu chez moi hier) or where the conversation takes place (Attends deux seconds, je reviens tout de suite). Retourner is to come back somwhere which is away from these places (J'ai envie de retourner chez moi) or to come back to an abstract location (Je suis retourné aux études).

Comment: Pourquoi pas tout simplement "Revenez (maintenant), vous (m')entendez ?" En effet, cette phrase impose une 2e personne du pluriel à cause du "all", qui précise qu'il y a plus d'une personne.

Comment: You all est une expression colloquiale en anglais qui est un pluriel. Donc, en aucun cas cela pourrait être rendu par tu en français. Désolée. Alors, c'est cinq "oui" sont bien de trop. Au chat, on dirait tu, mais si on dit You all, c'est bien vous dans le sens pluriel.

Comment: @Lambie En effet, "y'all" est d'habitude une expression pour s'addresser à plusieurs personnes. Mais étant américain, je saurais bien si ça peut s'appliquait au singulier. "Y'all" est surtout employé au sud des É.-U., où les gens ont tendance à être moins éduqués et parlent en mauvais anglais. Notez que l'OP a bien dit qu'il parlait à *son* chat, pas *ses* chats.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec cccg03 ; j'ai utilisé "y'all" pour plusieurs personnes _et_ pour juste une, et je suis bien éduqué, bien que je parle un peu familiale.

Comment: The OP was mistaken. You would not say you'all plural to a cat. It can be used as a singular, but the meaning is usually plural. It is not necessarily uneducated. Many educated people use it in the South in everyday speech. As an American and having lived in the South, I know exactly what I am talking about. In French, a colloquial rendering might be: Faut revenir, vous autres, eh?  for instance. It would NEVER be used with a cat in English, by the way.

Comment: In French, there are all sorts of way to render colloquial speech. That said, there is no way to render this colloquial plural as used in AmE other than by something like vous autres.

Comment: @Lambie The OP just agreed with me. He himself has used "y'all" in both the singular and plural. The fact that it is colloquial makes it pretty flexible in its use. If the OP said "y'all" to his one cat, who are you to tell him he's wrong?

Comment: @Lambie My answer was to reflect *his* specific situation. Had he been addressing himself to multiple cats (which he is perfectly allowed to do) or people, obviously I would have modified my answer.

Comment: I am saying a cat would not be "y'all" in American English. It's used for PEOPLE. In any case, it seems his original sentence was IN FRENCH, ergo: this "you all business" is just silly for this context. Tu doit retourner, tu entends? Is not "you all etc".

Comment: @Lambie "Tu **dois**" I interpreted the OP's question as addressing a French-speaking question in hopes of getting a better translation for the original sentence, which is his title. What's wrong with saying "y'all"  to animals, especially pets? It makes them more human. What's wrong with that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either sentence. But the English sentence is simply not a translation of the French one. You'd better come back, you hear me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38392/discussion-between-cccg03-and-lambie).